# Struts Form bean don't reset form field when submitted

Tags: struts, struts-1

How can I prevent a form bean field from being reset when submitted for validation. The thing here is, this form field is not a input field on the jsp. It is shown as normal html textlike this..

```
 <div class="label">
          <fmt:message bundle="${labels}" key="gender" />
 </div>
 <div class="data">
         <bean:write property="gender" name="infoForm"/>
 </div>
```

What is happening is that, when I click submit button and if there are any validation errors, all other input fields are populated again but this one gender field is not shown.

My guess is since the gender property here is not an input field, when the form is reset before or after validation, gender value is not populated. Am I correct? If so, what can I do to not reset this one particular field?

Answer (score 1):

If this information comes from a form in a previous page (for example if you're implementing a wizard, where a single big form is splitted into several pages), then you could use a form hidden field to store the information and resubmit it in every subsequent form.

If this is just information coming from the server (from the database, for example, or computed from other input fields), then you should simply get the information again from the database (or recompute it) and put it again in the form.

Comment: (Or if it's already being displayed correctly, as OP claims it is.)

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thanks for the reply. The information is coming from database. So when exactly do I put it again in the form after submit? If there are any validation errors, form is send back to view and it doesn't go through action class.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why Struts 1 sucks: validation should be handled by the action, and not by the form. But you can disable automatic form validation, call the validate method yourself in the action, and repopulate the form and forward to the input forward. If you can, definitely switch to Stripes or Spring MVC wich are, IMHO, really better than Struts 1.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I have added a hidden form field with same parameter...

```
    <html:hidden property="gender" name="infoForm"/>
```

that retained the field value after reset in validation...